avoid error 429 while sending request to specifically "Google"
I am trying to get some info from google using request.get(url) in python. Obviously after too many requests I got error 429. I want to change my headers so that this doesn't happen and also I don't want to use the method of putting time.sleep() to avoid the problem. I just want to know what am I supposed to do to change the headers.
I have also checked other stackoverflow solutions but in those they either tell to use time.sleep() or tell methods that doesn't specifically work with google servers.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me :)

I get where you're coming from but changing your headers isn't going to change anything. Rate limiting doesn't function by blocking specific headers, as headers can easily be altered. Instead, websites implement rate limiting by tracking the IP addresses of incoming requests. When an IP address exceeds the allowed number of requests within a certain timeframe, it is temporarily banned or restricted. To bypass this limit, you could either wait until the restriction is lifted after a certain period or use a proxy. Using a proxy involves routing requests through different IP addresses, thereby evading the rate limit imposed on the original IP address.
Below is an example on how you can use proxies in python requests:
import requests

def send_request_through_proxy(proxy_url):
    proxy_settings = {
        "http": proxy_url,
        "https": proxy_url
    }
    response = requests.get("https://google.com", proxies=proxy_settings)
    
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy_address = "http://your_proxy_ip:port"
    resp = send_request_through_proxy(proxy_address)
    print(resp.status_code)


you get a 429 code because you are sending too many requests to Google. Send less requests hence the suggestions of using time.sleep(). Changing headers is not going to help.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Is it not possible for my requests to be fake/pretend to be from a browser?

yes, but sending large numbers of requests from a single process is always likely to trigger at least a 429. You may also encounter your ip address being limited in communication to Google in other ways. The server is protecting itself from DDoS and other attacks.

No my intention is not to send large amount of requests or perform ddos attacks. The problem is I cant reduce the number requests since they are already very very less and also they are not too frequent. I sent a few today morning and I got error 429. The thing is many hours later this evening I sent a request from a different machine a different router at a different location and I still get error 429.

Maybe if you describe what you are trying to achieve in another question you might get a different answer but for a 429 the only mechanism is to limit your requests.

Also to mention Google do provide a Search API which can be used https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Sure I will taka a look at that API thank you for your support

@briask the question is about "How to bypass the rate limit" and your answer is "Do not bypass the rate limit". worthless answer honestly.
